# Performing a large number of 2-sample t-tests in R

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics

So I am creating a function which allows me to take a data.frame and get a dataframe of p.values for each variable tested.

```
    # data and labels
my_data <- data.frame(matrix(data = rnorm(10000), nrow = 100, ncol = 10000))
labels <- sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE)


# append the labels to the data, then filter
my_data$labels <- labels

sample_1 <- dplyr::filter(.data = my_data, labels == 0)
sample_2 <- dplyr::filter(.data = my_data, labels == 1)


#perform a t-test on each column
p_vals <- data.frame()
for(i in c(1:10000)) {
    p_vals <- rbind(p_vals, t.test(x = sample_1[,i], y = sample_2[,i])$p.value)
}

return(p_vals)
```

This is functional, but I think/hope there would be a more efficient way to do this without the for loop. The data should be in rows because for later functions it will be important to keep track of which variable had which p value.

Comment: could we have a [mcve] please?  You shouldn't "grow"  your result object: you should pre-allocate space.  Your `p_vals` is just a vector, right?

Comment: yeah it is. @BenBolker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of splitting the samples you can use the formula interface to `t.test`, and `sapply` over the columns of `my_data` to conduct the tests:

```
p_vals <- sapply( my_data, function(x) t.test(x ~ labels)$p.value )
```

This will make a vector of p-values, the order will be the same as the columns of `my_data`

Comment: This worked for me with a few changes. Thanks! I just had to put and unlist() around x and labels as well as not include the column of labels in the analysis

Comment: @paxton that's strange.  it works exactly as is for me if I create `mydata` and `labels` using your code (though I don't add the `labels` column to `mydata`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the package genefilter:

```
library(genefilter)
colttests(as.matrix(my_data[,-ncol(my_data)]),factor(my_data$labels))
```